# Sorting by key, and value in a Python Dictionary (By alphabet && Numerical Descendance @ the same time)

Tags: python-3.x

I see there are 2 other threads with posts about a similar question, but they are in c# and java respectively.

## Conversely, this is a post about python 3.x .

---

Please review my code below. If you look closely and run this source, you will see I can successfully sort the dictionary by only the key value for key=lambda t: t[0].
This is good, it sorts by alphabet. This is what I need.
But, the problem is: I need to sort this by alphabet and descending numerical order (for the value portion of the dictionary) respectively.
For example if you change the t[0] to t[1] , you will see the results for the value portion of the dictionary{} item sort by number.

What I need is to sort by both t[0] && t[1] . && operators don't seem to be working.

I'm thinking of trying a different data structure?

---

Code :

```
from collections import OrderedDict
from collections import Counter
import string


def analyze(codebook):
    dict = {'A':0, 'B':0,'C':0,'D':0,'E':0,'F':0,'G':0,'H':0,'I':0,'J':0,'K':0,'L':0,'M':0,'N':0,'O':0,'P':0,'Q':0,'R':0,'S':0,'T':0,'U':0,'V':0,'W':0,'X':0,'Y':0,'Z':0}

    #Capitalize codebook string here.
    cap_codebook= codebook.upper()

    ctr = Counter(cap_codebook)

    

    sortedCtr = sorted(ctr.items(), key=lambda t: t[0])     
    return sortedCtr



    
    
def main():
    # read the code from input
    codebook = input("Please enter the codebook: ")
    
    freq = analyze(codebook)
    print (freq)
   
   
main()
```

Comment: Usually this would mean that if the first values are equal (the keys), you would sort by the second values (the dict values).  That shouldn't be a problem for you, because you'll never have two equal keys (dictionaries can only have one of any key)

Comment: When I say key, I'm referring to the dictionary data structure in python.
For example a dictionary data structure is composed of 2 things: key,value. (e.g 'A':0)

But, what i'm wondering is if there is a way to use my current method to sort by both key & value at the same time.. With regard to key and value being alphabetical sorting and numerical sorting respectively.

Comment: What do you mean "at the same time"? Generally, when you're sorting on multiple attributes you end up with something like `comp((A, B), (C, D)) = B  > D if A == C else A > C`

Comment: By at the same time I mean for it to be alphabetize and descending numerically. Like : Alphabetical order and descending numerical order.
Hope that makes sense!